# Symfony2/3 Children Entity Constraint Assert ignored

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a situation where the validation constraints inside the entity classes are ignored...

This one does not work (which is a children of ActivityField Entity):

```
<?php
namespace XXX\ActivityFieldsBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use XXX\DatabaseBundle\Entity\AbstractEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="XXX\ActivityFieldsBundle\Repository\ActivityFieldLanguagesRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @ORM\Table(name="activity_field_languages")
 */
class ActivityFieldLanguages extends AbstractEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="text")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()    ----> !!! this one here !!!
     */
    protected $name;
```

while this one (which is standalone does not have any connection to other entities) works:

```
<?php

namespace XXX\LanguagesBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use XXX\DatabaseBundle\Entity\AbstractEntity;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use XXX\CommonBundle\Validator\Constraints as SiteAssert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="XXX\LanguagesBundle\Repository\LanguagesRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @ORM\Table(name="languages")
 *
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="name")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="iso")
 */
class Languages extends AbstractEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank() -----> this one here !!!
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min=2,
     *     minMessage="validator.minimum.2.characters"
     * )
     */
    protected $name;
```

If i add the constraint in FormType then all is ok and working but I don't want to have that and keep everything in the Entity file as annotation.
In my config file i have

```
framework:
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
```

Comment: In annotation all ok. Which mode you work (prod, dev)? Try clear cache (The annotation will cached after complete parse)?

Comment: i'm in dev env. I just cleared (hard delete) the cache, restart server, clear redis still the same ... maybe some config missing? although Languages works just fine ...

Comment: Is the entity part of another parent entity? Otherwise you need to add `@Assert\Valid()` to the parent relationship annotation.

Comment: @Rvanlaak that's it. Please add it as an answer and I will accept it! I's a child of ActivityField. I also edited the question to be more clear based on your answer!

Comment: This is a tough one to debug, I've added some more info to my answer below

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To "pass through" the validation to child formtypes, you need to add `@Assert\Valid` to the parent type.

So related to the Doctrine entity, if `ActivityFieldLanguages` is a child entity of let's say `ActivityField` then the parent should mark that relationship for validation.

```
/**
 * @var ActivityFieldLanguages[] $activityFieldLanguages
 * @Assert\Valid()
 */
protected $activityFieldLanguages;
```

If you want to do this directly in your `FormType`, you should add that same constraint to the (probably) `CollectionType`:

```
$formBuilder->add('activityFieldLanguages', CollectionType::class, array(
    // ...
    'constraints' => new Valid()
);
```

For more info: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html

Answer (score 0):

May be you have validation groups and 'name' is not included in that group that group you might be used in your form. This can cause such logical errors.